# IP Access restriction using Istio not working

Tags: istio

I am trying to implement IP-based access restriction using Istio where I would like Istio to block all requests apart from Certain IPs. I got to a point where It's blocking the requests but it's not allowing the IPs I add in the YAML Manifest. I suspect the IP that it is seeing is different that the original Client IP as I have a couple of Load Balancers in front of my Istio.

I read from some documents that X-Forwarder-For is what we should be using to get the actual IP and I have used this in some other implementations but unclear how to get Istio to pick the actual X-Forwarder-Host. Can we create some custom headers and make Istio read from there? Please help

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-policy
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        remoteIpBlocks: ["98.XXX.XXX.66"]
```

I enabled Debug Logs in my Envoy and below is what is getting recorded.

`[2023-05-13T03:22:05.387Z] "GET /cluster/XXXX/XXXX/hari5 HTTP/1.1" 403 - rbac_access_denied_matched_policy[none] - "-" 0 19 0 - "98.XXX.XXX.66:52063,10.240.208.62" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "37ccfaa6-7deb-414f-9f5c-72926c997994" "XXX-XX-XXX.XXX.com" "-" outbound|80||XXX.XXX-XXX.svc.cluster.local - 10.240.208.23:8080 10.240.208.62:40755 - -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we had to use for restricting GET-access based on IP for one of our apps.

The x-forwarded-for header is just a comma-delimited string where first entry is the client IP-address, the remaining IP-addresses are from gateway, proxy etc.

- For match with single IP-address: E.g. "123.234.345.567,*" (note the comma before the wild-card character is important when last segment is less than 3 digits)
- For match with all addresses in last segment: E.g. "123.234.345.*"
- For match with all addresses in 2 last segments: E.g. "123.234.*"

You may also add multiple IP-patterns under `values`.

I hope this will bring you further.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: our-authorization-policy
  namespace: our-namespace
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: our-app-name
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
    - to:
        - operation:
            methods: ["GET"]
      when:
        - key: request.headers[x-forwarded-for]
          values:
            - "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,*" # note the trailing '*'
```

Comment: Will I be able to use a CIDR , Multiple IP Blocks with such implementation ?

Comment: @HariNarayanan: According to this Istio-issue, it does not: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/40131, but I added a workaround in my answer to support ranges of IP-addresses. BR

Comment: I tried enabling it and still not able to get it to work , unclear if I am missing something , does this have a dependency on setting the externalTrafficPolicy to local ?

Comment: Never mind , figured it out , the had to modify the regex , Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect the IP that it is seeing is different that the original
> Client IP as I have a couple of Load Balancers in front of my Istio.

Assuming you don't use  `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` because as described [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/#ip-based-allow-list-and-deny-list) you have used `remoteIpBlocks`. So if you comply with that the only issue I am seeing is the following.

The load balancer is the one component that sits between the client and Istio. Therefore it should be the load balancer that reads the client's IP and adds this value to the header `X-Forwarded-For`. Then Istio would be able to understand and filter the request based on the Client's Ip address.

Comment: Yes ,The X-Forwarded-For is getting appended by the Application Gateway thats sites in front of the Istio Ingress Gateway Internal Local Balancer . Based on the Above YAML will istio automatically know this and compare the IP with the header automatically ? Or what will be the behavior . Do you think the above YAML should work as is ? or am I missing something as it dosent seem like its working